# okhttp: how to handle unrequested/unexpected 100 (continue) response from server?

Tags: android, okhttp

TLDR: Is there a way to force OkHttp to correctly handle unexpected/unrequested 100 Continue HTTP responses?

I'm using OkHttp 3.8.1 on Android to POST to a poorly-behaved server.

Even though the request does not include an "Expect: 100-continue" header, the web server returns a 100 Continue response.  Rather than continuing to send the request body, then getting the actual (200) response, OkHttp stops there and sends back the 100 Continue response in my okhttp.Callback.

I tried explicitly including "Expect: 100-continue" in the request to trigger OkHttp's logic, but the server (possibly due to some bug) claims the header is malformed and rejects the request.  I also tried sending "Expect:" (no value), but the server still sends the 100 Continue response and OkHttp stops there.

Other HTTP clients (I've tested 3 so far) can talk to that server just fine.  They handle the 100 Continue response correctly even though they didn't see "Expect: 100-continue" in the request header.  Is there an option I can set, or an interceptor I can write, to make OkHttp do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like something we can fix in OkHttp. This is weird and the server is broken, but if other clients handle it OkHttp should too.

Please report a bug there?